# how to reset form or everything on reload or refresh using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i tried doing autocomplete off but it does not do anything. The radio or input is still selected.

```
$('input,textarea').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

on reset I either want to preselect the first input or no input is selected

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input, textarea').val('')
                    .prop('selected', false)
                    .prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: it resets but the selection stay im using radio btw or check label to be exact

Answer (score 0):

Wtap it with `<form id="formid">` and use `$('#formid')[0].reset();`